# Finding every possible list made by removing the first element from either of two lists and appending to the new list

Tags: python, permutation

I have two lists of ints, a and b, which do not necessarily have the same length. I would like to create new lists from these by removing either the first element of a, or the first element of b, and appending it to the new list, repeating this step until both a and b are empty. At each step in this process, the number of possible lists grows exponentially, and I'd like to know how to generate every list that is possible to create in this way.

So far, I've only managed to work out that the number of possible lists is equal to `sum((2**i for i in range(len(a) + len(b))))`. I have no idea how to proceed with this, and would appreciate any pointers.

For information, my end goal is to work out the sum of the differences between consecutive elements for each list, and find the minimum of these.

Comment: `itertools.permutations(a+b)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be achieved by using recursion. Some code.

```
permutation = [0]*10 # size of this list has to be equal to lenth of list1 + length of list2. (you can have 4 as the size of the list).
def task(list1,list2,index):
    if len(list1)==0 and len(list2)==0: # if length of both the list is 0, we print the 
        print(permutation)              # permutation list
        return

    if len(list1)>0:    
        permutation[index] = list1[0]
        modified_list1 = list1[:]       # Since lists in python are passed by reference, I am making a copy of the list
        modified_list1.pop(0)           # Removing the first element
        task(modified_list1,list2,index+1) #and calling the function again using the modified list.

    if len(list2)>0:
        permutation[index] = list2[0]
        modified_list2 = list2[:]
        modified_list2.pop(0)
        task(list1,modified_list2,index+1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    list1 = [1]
    list2 = [4,5,6]
    task(list1,list2,0)
```

Recursive solutions can be a little tricky to understand, I will encourage you
to take a copy and pen and try simulating it for small input, you will
understand how things are working.

For your next task, when we are printing the permutation list, you can compute the differences of the adjacent numbers and store your result in any way you want.

Comment: This does exactly what I want, thanks. It would be nice to make the function more self-contained by defining `permutation` inside the `task()`, but I haven't figured that out yet, and it's not vital anyway.